# Different colors for flight routes leaflet with R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am stuck with a problem with leaflet.
I want to plot flight routes (already done with gcIntermediate) but i want to colour the routes based on a factor variable (Status:cancelled,delayed).
I would want delayed routes colored with blue and the cancelled ones with red

**my R code**:

```
gcIntermediate(coord1[,c(1,2)], coord1[,c(3,4)],  
               n=100,   
               addStartEnd=TRUE,  
               sp=TRUE) %>%   
  leaflet() %>%   
  addTiles() %>%   
  setView(-100,38, zoom = 4.49) %>%   
  addPolylines(color="red") %>%   
  addMarkers(lng=c(coord1[,1],coord1[,3]),lat=c(coord1[,2],coord1[,4]))
```

where coord1 is a dataframe with: the latitudes and logitudes of two cities and the factor variable(status).

Comment: Could you provide some example data so we can run your code?

Comment: coord1 <- data.frame("Longitud1" = c(-84.42694,-82.42694,-104.66700), "Latitud1"=c(33.64044,33.64044,39.85841),"Longitud2"=c(-97.03720,-80.15275,-112.00806),"Latitud2"=c(32.89595,26.07258,33.43417),"estado"=c("Delayed","Delayed","Cancelled"))

Comment: I think I've made it! :D

Comment: gcIntermediate(coord1[,c(1,2)], coord1[,c(3,4)],  
               n=100, 
               addStartEnd=TRUE,
               sp=TRUE) %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(-100,38, zoom = 4.49) %>% 
  addPolylines(color=colores(coord1)) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=c(coord1[,1],coord1[,3]),lat=c(coord1[,2],coord1[,4]))

    colores<-function(df){
  color<-c()
  for( i in 1: nrow(coord1)){
  if (df$estado[i]=="Cancelled") {
    color<-c(color,"red")
    }else{
      color<-c(color,"orange")
    }
    
  }
  return(color)
  }

Comment: Instead of adding the info in the comment section, you should edit your post.

Comment: And if you've worked out an answer, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        coord1 <- data.frame("Longitud1" = c(-84.42694,-82.42694,-104.66700),   
  "Latitud1"=c(33.64044,33.64044,39.85841), 
 "Longitud2"=c(-97.03720,-80.15275,-112.00806), 
     "Latitud2"=c(32.89595,26.07258,33.43417), 
     "estado"=c("Delayed","Delayed","Cancelled"))
```

And the answer is:

```
colores<-function(df){ color<-c() for( i in 1: nrow(coord1)){ if (df$estado[i]=="Cancelled") { color<-c(color,"red") }else{ color<-c(color,"orange") } } return(color) } 

 gcIntermediate(coord1[,c(1,2)], coord1[,c(3,4)], n=100, addStartEnd=TRUE, sp=TRUE) %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-100,38, zoom = 4.49) %>% addPolylines(color=colores(coord1)) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=c(coord1[,1],coord1[,3]),lat=c(coord1[,2],coord1[,4]))
```